# I just got this exercise today and understood it quite well, although I want to practice more.

Tags: terminology, fractions

So this isn't really a post asking for help in the operation itself but to know how you call it in English.

[image: expression]

I would like to know it so that I can do some research online and get some practice done.

Comment: Try "continued fractions".

Comment: right, that might be it actually. Thanks!

Comment: Looks more like simplifying complex fractions than anything else, also there is no need for the differential equations tag as it's unrelated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i will compute the denominator: $$5-\frac{1}{2-\frac{3}{2}}$$
$$2-\frac{3}{2}=\frac{4-3}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$ and we have $$5-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}}=5-2=3$$
can you compute the denominator?
at first you must compute $$1-\frac{1}{5}=\frac{4}{5}$$ and $$\frac{1}{\frac{4}{5}}=\frac{5}{4}$$ and then go on with $$1-\frac{5}{4}$$ and so on

Comment: I think I got it, can't end it though. I just don't know when/how to apply the ''1-'' that is in the beginning.https://imgur.com/a/hzhx2

Comment: Yes! I am pretty sure I got it!

Comment: and who gave me the $-2$?

Comment: The final answer is -4?